# Novel in which a girl reincarnates into the body of a legal daughter who's killed by a concubine and thrown down a cliff

Tags: story-identification, novel

It's a Chinese novel where the female lead is transmigrated into the body of the daughter of a general and killed by her stepmother, then thrown down a cliff.

Later she's found by a group of people, like a sect, where she stays for a few years. She moves out and forms her own group of highly trained assassins, then goes back to capital to take revenge for the original owner of the body.

The female lead's father who is a general wasn't aware of all the abuse the concubine was doing to the owner of the body.

The female lead is also poisoned so she goes through severe pain every month or few months. When her subordinates go to search for the flower which can save her life they meet the male lead, whose life she once saved a few years back in the forest.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a physical book, e-book or a webnovel?  A light novel or manhua?